# Why isn't my onclick event listener on my radio buttons not working?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, radio-button, dom-events

```html
<form id="color-options" name="FormB">
       <input type="radio" name="choice" value="blue" onclick="updateColor()">
       <label for="blue">Blue</label>
       <input type="radio" name="choice" value="red" onclick="updateColor()" >
       <label for="red">Red</label>
       <input type="radio" name="choice" value="white" onclick="updateColor()" >
       <label for="white">White</label>
       <input type="radio" name="choice" value="user" onclick="updateColor()">
       <label for="color-picker">Color Picker</label>
       <input type="color" id="color-picker"> 
     </form>
      <div id="Sketch">

        <div id="tile">

        </div>
      </div>
```

```
    let tile = document.getElementById("tile")
    let radio = document.forms[1] // //forms[1] is accessing the 2nd form because u have a form before it.
    function updateColor() {
        for (let i = 0; i < radio.choice.length; i++) {   //document.forms returns a collection of everything that has a form tag
            if (radio.choice[i].checked ) {  //form.choice = returns an array of the radio buttons, incrementing i to traverse along the array
                //checked returns a boolean if the button is checked or not; ask if the button is clicked or not and if it is follow this new loop
               for (let i = 0; i < radio.choice[i].length; i++) { //this new loop iterates and asks if the value is a certain color, and if it is change the background color
                    if (radio.choice[i].value === "blue") {
                            tile.style.backgroundColor= "blue";
                    } else if (radio.choice[i].value === "red") {
                            tile.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
                            } else if (radio.choice[i].value === "white") {
                                tile.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
                            } else if (radio.choice[i].value === "user") {
                                tile.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
                            }
                        }
                    } 
                } 
            }
```

So I'm trying to get the tile to change colors when it is hovered on depending on which option is selected. (For the example right now it's just set to change the background color for simplicity purposes although I still haven't figured out to do it onhover). So what I tried to do was iterate over the form group to see if anything is checked or not, and then if it is move on to a nested loop which asks if the value is a certain color. I feel like i have the logic down right, but nothing activates and I'm not sure what else i can do. But obviously there's a mistake I'm just not catching.

https://jsfiddle.net/Jbautista1056/0gxf2Lpq/1/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to loop through the form to check which element is checked. Using `updateColor(this)` is enough:

```js
function updateColor(element) {
  const selectedColor = element.value !== 'user' ? element.value : 'green';
  const title = document.getElementById("tile");
  tile.style.backgroundColor = selectedColor;
}
```

```css
#tile {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="blue" onclick="updateColor(this)">
<label for="blue">Blue</label>
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="red" onclick="updateColor(this)" >
<label for="red">Red</label>
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="white" onclick="updateColor(this)" >
<label for="white">White</label>
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="user" onclick="updateColor(this)">
<label for="white">User</label>
<br /><br />
<div id="tile"></div>
```

Comment: I like this solution but I'm confused as to how updateColor(this) and the parameter element tie into this. Where does the element parameter get it's value from?

Comment: @JosemariBautista `this` represents the HTML DOM element. For example, when you click on the first radio (the one with the blue value), the whole element is passed to updateColor() and `this` is the representation of that radio element in the HTML DOM. If you console.log(this), you'll have access to the whole element and it's attributes, like element.id, element.name, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use CSS selectors to grab the 'checked' radio buttom by doing `document.querySelector('#color-options > input:checked')`. You can then get the value of the checked radio button by adding `.value` to the end.

So in total; `document.querySelector('#color-options > input:checked').value`. No looping required, no params required.

Comment: wow this good to know! I can't believe I went through all that hard work just to loop around everything lol

Comment: Always the way. :p

Comment: Does document.querySelector('#color-options > input:checked') give you a boolean return value?

Comment: Afraid not. It looks at the DOM and tries to find a matching node. If it can't find one it returns `null`, if it can it returns that element.

Comment: I've tried to implement this code into my file but the color still doesn't change. I also changed the onclick="" in the html file to the new function. This is what I've done. https://pastebin.com/CkKR0zyJ

Comment: I would imagine it is getting the `.value` at the start and never updating, sec, I'll make a JSFiddle. :)

Comment: Here: https://jsfiddle.net/gm10nfha/

If you do `document.querySelector('#color-options > input:checked')` at the top of the document, it'll grab the element once and never update. So you need to query the 'checked' node every time. If that makes sense?


It works fine for `tile` as the element never changes, whereas as the 'checked' element varies every single time. :)